# intEff function R returns weird errors

Tags: r, statistics, binary-data, glm, economics

I have the following probit model with an interaction effect between i and a:

```
probit5 <- glm(y ~ a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j + k + l + i*a,
           family = binomial(link = "probit"), 
           data = data)
```

But when I use the intEff function:

```
intEff(probit5, c("i", "a"), data = data)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : 
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
In addition: Warning message:
In cbind(deriv1, deriv2, deriv3, nn, deriv0) :
  number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 4)
```

the data frame "data" looks like this, and class says it's a data.frame

[image]

**Reproducable example:**

```
a <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
b <- c(18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18)
c <- c(3.667, 3.667, 3.667, 3.667, 3.667, 3.667, 3.667, 3.667, 3.667, 3.667)
d <- c(4.8, 4.8, 4.8, 4.8, 4.8, 4.8, 4.8, 4.8, 4.8, 4.8)
e <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
f <- c(4.54, 4.54, 4.54, 4.54, 4.54, 4.54, 4.54, 4.54, 4.54, 4.54)
g <- c(3.6364, 3.6364, 3.6364, 3.6364, 3.6364, 3.6364, 3.6364, 3.6364, 3.6364, 3.6364)
h <- c(2.8, 2.8, 2.8, 2.8, 2.8, 2.8, 2.8, 2.8, 2.8, 2.8)
i <- c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0)
j <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
k <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
l <- c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
y <- c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

data <- data.frame(y, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l)

probit <- glm(y ~ a + b + c + d + e + f + g  + h + i + j + k + l + i*a,
               family = binomial(link = "probit"), 
               data = data)

intEff(probit, c("i", "a"), data = data)
```

But this shows the following error:

```
Error in apply(X[, vars], 2, table) : dim(X) must have a positive length
```

Maybe it is important to note that data.csv was imported with read.csv2

The coefficients of the real example:

[image]

Comment: what package is the `intEff` function from?  Can we have a [mcve] please ... ?

Comment: It is from the DAMisc package. I will try to make a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: as of 20 Mar 2020 the example above works for me (version 1.6.2 of DAMisc)

Answer (score 2):

The proximal problem in your example might be that most of your coefficients are `NA`.  I'm not **sure** that's your actual problem (it's driven by the multicollinearity in your very short example), but maybe you could check/edit your question to show the coefficients of `probit5` in your real example?

```
coef(probit)

##   (Intercept)             a             b             c             d 
## -6.552767e+00            NA            NA            NA            NA 
##            e             f             g             h             i 
##           NA            NA            NA            NA  2.970389e-16 
##            j             k             l           a:i 
##           NA            NA  1.310553e+01            NA
```